# gRPC Python thread_pool vs max_concurrent_rpcs

Tags: python, grpc, concurrent.futures

When launching a Python `grpc.server`, what's the difference between `maximum_concurrent_rpcs` and the `max_workers` used in the thread pool. If I want `maximum_concurrent_rpcs=1`, should I still provide more than one thread to the thread pool?

In other words, should I match `maximum_concurrent_rpcs` to my `max_workers`, or should I provide more workers than max concurrent RPCs?

```
server = grpc.server(
    thread_pool=futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1),
    maximum_concurrent_rpcs=1,
)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your server already processing `maximum_concurrent_rpcs` number of requests concurrently, and yet another request is received, the request will be rejected immediately.

If the ThreadPoolExecutor's `max_workers` is less than `maximum_concurrent_rpcs` then after all the threads get busy processing requests, the next request will be queued and will be processed when a thread finishes its processing.

I had the same question. To answer this, I debugged a bit what happens with `maximum_concurrent_rpcs`. The debugging went to `py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_server.py` in my `virtualenv`. Search for `concurrency_exceeded`. The bottom line is that if the server is already processing `maximum_concurrent_rpcs` and another request arrives, it will be rejected:

```
# ...
elif concurrency_exceeded:
    return _reject_rpc(rpc_event, cygrpc.StatusCode.resource_exhausted,
                        b'Concurrent RPC limit exceeded!'), None
# ...
```

I tried it with the `gRPC` Python Quickstart example:

- [gRPC quick start python example](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html)

In the `greeter_server.py` I modified the `SayHello()` method:

```
# ...
def SayHello(self, request, context):
    print("Request arrived, sleeping a bit...")
    time.sleep(10)
    return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)
# ...
```

and the `serve()` method:

```
def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10), maximum_concurrent_rpcs=2)
    # ...
```

Then I opened 3 terminals and executed the client in them manually (as fast as I could using `python greeter_client.py`:

As expected, for the first 2 clients, processing of the request started immediately (can be seen in the server's output), because there were plenty of threads available, but the 3rd client got rejected immediately (as expected) with `StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED`, `Concurrent RPC limit exceeded!`.

Now to test what happens when there are not enough threads given to `ThreadPoolExecutor` I modified the `max_workers` to be 1:

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1), maximum_concurrent_rpcs=2)
```

I ran my 3 clients again roughly the same time as previously.

**The results is** that the first one got served immediately. The second one needed to wait 10 seconds (while the first one was served) and then it was served. The third one got rejected immediately.